# Cannot get CodeSniffer working in (any) Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, phpcodesniffer

i installed Eclipse then installed the latest PDT, then CodeSniffer from the official update site. After restarting eclipse, nothing changes. No validation at all. I can manually start PHP CodeSniffer on a selected file, but nothing happens.
Tried with Juno (4.2) and Kepler (4.3), even with Indigo. Nothing works. All the howto sites simply tell to install CodeSniffer from the update site, but it doesnt work.

Does anyone know how to get this working, so it prints warnings in my problem panel?
I installed it on command line as well using "pear install PHP_CodeSniffer". Calling it manually on command line works fine, but not in eclipse.

PEAR library is set to internal, selected Zend as Standard. PHP Exec is also set to my custom compiled one under /usr/local/bin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to delete my .metadata and all settings, so i can start from scratch.
Had to add all my projects back again, but at least CodeSniffer was working.
So something was blocking it.